# How to set a Google Map's center by ID?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a good map on my page. I would like to set the center of it from a function call in javascript? Does the map have an elementID or anything I can reference it in javascript with?

Comment: A link to your code/application would help.

Comment: Can you throw up some code on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: I found the problem, I was trying to set the maps center before the map was loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normally you first create an options obecjt wihich also contains center of the map like
and then you pass it to map object.

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(geolen, geowidth);

var options = {

  center: latlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  disableDefaultUI: true,
  mapTypeControl: true,
  scaleControl: true
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_container"), options);
```

After creating a map, you can always manipulate the map options using `map` instance. I think you don't need any `ElementID` for setting or getting the center of `map`

Comment: I'm trying to reference it inside a seperate function. I have tried using map using map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long)); but it tells me map is undefined.

Comment: That's probably because `map` is defined with `var` inside a function (which makes it local to the function). Add `var map;` in global scope and assign `map` not `var map` inside the function.

Comment: I've already got that. var map is global and I use map in the functions